# How to create wild card sub domain in Magento 1.9.x

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore, url-rewrite, htaccess, subdomain

I am coming with question of how to create a wildcard subdomain in **Magento 1.9.x** without using **store view**. I know creating more store view will cause the issues in price indexing, flat tables, etc.,

I have countless subdomains.

**I tried:**

- Created the wild card setup in cpanel using A record. `*.example.com  IN  A 127.0.0.1`
- then when calling `sub1.example.com & sub2.example.com & sub3.example.com` its pointed to `example.com`.
- added needed stuff in `.htaccess`.

**Problems am having:**

- when we load `sub1.example.com` all urls needs to `http://sub1.example.com/...` but currently loads `http://example.com/...` I know its from db, so how to rewrite `getUrl()` for this case.

So I need a suggestion for load sub domains same like a main website without creating multiple store views.

**Note:** I did lot of digging in google & SO & ME.

Please suggest the possible ways to solve.

Comment: Don't thought it will be possible without store view

Comment: @AmitBera can you explain more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally find the solution for this after digging, I know its a hard code *(not suggested this way)* but i am in need to share my answer to ME and I hope will get the better answer when compared to this with out affecting core module.

**Reason for why the sub domain redirected:**

`app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php`

In `dispatch()` method

```
 // If pre-configured, check equality of base URL and requested URL
 $this->_checkBaseUrl($request);
```

Magento matching the requested url with base url, if not matched with (host or ..) they redirected to base url.

```
/**
 * Auto-redirect to base url (without SID) if the requested url doesn't match it.
 * By default this feature is enabled in configuration.
 *
 * @param Zend_Controller_Request_Http $request
 */
protected function _checkBaseUrl($request){
    .....
}
```

so plan to get the needed subdomain informtaion using this event `controller_front_init_before before` dispatch and set the new baseurl in cache

**copied below files from core pool to local pool**
`app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php` to `app/code/local/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php`

`app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Store.php` to `app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/Store.php`

added event in **config.xml**

```
<events>
    <controller_front_init_before>
        <observers>
            <observer_name>
                <class>modelname/observer</class>
                <method>controllerFrontIntBefore</method>
            </observer_name>
        </observers>
    </controller_front_init_before>
</events>
```

**observer.php**

```
public function controllerFrontIntBefore($observer)
{
    Mage::helper('helperclass')->MethodSetUrl();
    return $this;
}
```

**Data.php**

```
public function coreSession(){
    return Mage::getSingleton('core/session');
}

public function getSubDomain(){
    return Mage::registry('cur_subdomain') ? strtolower(Mage::registry('cur_subdomain')->getSubDomain()) : false;
}

public function MethodSetUrl(){
    try{
        $currentSubDomain = false;
        $getUrl  = $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"];
        $split_url = explode(".", $getUrl);
        $subAccount = Mage::getModel('model/modelname')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('sub_domain', @strtolower($split_url[0]));
        if($subAccount->count()){
            $currentSubDomain = $subAccount->getFirstItem();
            $this->coreSession()->setSubDomain($currentSubDomain);
        }
        Mage::register('cur_subdomain', $currentDist);
    }catch (Exception $e){
        Mage::throwException($e->getMessage());
    }
    $baseUrl = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB,Mage::app()->getStore()->isCurrentlySecure());
}

public function setBaseUrlGlobal($url){
    try{
        if(Mage::registry('cur_subdomain')){
            $curDistKeyShop = $this->getSubDomain();
            if($url){
                $httpReg = (@$_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") ? "https://" : "http://";
                $splitUrl = explode('.', $url);
                $subDomain = str_replace($httpReg,'', $splitUrl['0']);
                $reqSubDomain = @explode(".", $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]);
                $reqSubDomain = str_replace($httpReg,'', $reqSubDomain);
                if($reqSubDomain && $reqSubDomain != $this->subDomain && $reqSubDomain != $this->Domain){
                    $splitUrl['0'] = $httpReg.$curDistKeyShop;
                    $url = implode('.', $splitUrl);
                }
            }
        }
    }catch (Exception $e){
        Mage::throwException($e->getMessage());
    }
    return $url;
}
```

**app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/Store.php**

`public function getBaseUrl($type = self::URL_TYPE_LINK, $secure = null)
    {
        ................
        ................
        $this->_baseUrlCache[$cacheKey] = Mage::helper('helpername')->setBaseUrlGlobal($this->_baseUrlCache[$cacheKey]);
       return $this->_baseUrlCache[$cacheKey];
    }`

I hope everything over for now.

And i have tried all the possible ways of getting baseurl in below ways

its returned as sub domain urls as excepted

```
$url = $this->getUrl();
$baseUrl= Mage::getBaseUrl();
$websiteUrl = Mage::getConfig()->getNode('web/unsecure/base_url', 'website', 'code');
$currentUrl = Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();
$skinUrl = $this->getSkinUrl('images/imagename.jpg');
$storeUrl = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB);
$homeUrl= Mage::helper('core/url')->getHomeUrl();

$request = $this->getRequest();
$urlWithoutParameters = $this->getBaseUrl() . $request->getRouteName() .DS. $request->getControllerName() .DS. $request->getActionName();
```

Looking for suggetsion for this answers and another possible ways too.

Comment: Is that working properly ?

Comment: as i tested its working vicky may be some where i missed anything pls suggest your solutions

Answer (score 3):

You will need to rewrite the following classes for starter

```
Mage_Page_Block_Html_Topmenu
Mage_Page_Block_Html_Footer
Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Url
Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Item
```

like below

```
 <global>
        <blocks>
            <page>
                <rewrite>      
             <html_topmenu>Module_name_Block_Page_Html_Topmenu</html_topmenu>
                <html_footer>Module_name_Block_Page_Html_Footer</html_footer>
                </rewrite>
            </page>
        </blocks>
        <models>
            <catalog>
                <rewrite>     
           <product_url>Module_name_Model_Catalog_Product_Url</product_url> 
               <layer_filter_item>Module_name_Model_Catalog_Layer_Filter_Item</layer_filter_item>
                </rewrite>
            </catalog>
        </models>
 </global>
```

and this will give you Overall getUrl, getBaseUrl functions to put your incoming base url with actual db base url, if you don't have any static base urls in theme + base url redirection not enabled in db level then this will work for you.

**Note:** 
- having wildcard subdomain and same url/content will have effect in SEO

Comment: let me try and back to you ela

Comment: I have tried this its seems long process to achieve this, can we overwrite the core modules?